# How to set different configuration for multiple functions in single function app in Azure?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I m trying to set different configuration for two functions in the single Azure Function App, but I m not able to implement it or able to find any proper documentation on how to implement it. Have all MS documents but its not mentioned any where there also.
Below is how I want to set the configuration for different functions:

```
[functionTimeout("00:10:00")]
public void Function1([ServiceBusTrigger] input)
{
 //some code
}

[functionTimeout("00:30:00")]
[BatchSize(5)]
public void Function2([ServiceBusTrigger] input)
{
 //some code
}
```

I want to implement something like this. Any one here has idea on how to do it? or even if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. When you have two different configurations for different functions, you can split those functions into separate Function Apps.

Take the [batch size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) for example. This is a trigger setting, not a function setting. And all functions of the same trigger type are configured via [`host.json` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json), with an exception of some basic parameters (such as queue name as an example).