# How can you configure different prefetch settings using ServiceBusTrigger in a azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

Today i'm configuring PrefetchCount in startup.cs like below. However, we have multiple functions using the ServiceBusTrigger in the same project. How can I configure different PrefetchCount for each function?

```
builder.Services.Configure((ServiceBusOptions options) =>
{
    options.PrefetchCount = 20;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As specified in this SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44431623) given by @*MikhailShilkov* and [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json), if you define the `PrefetchCount` in `host.json` code, then it acts as a global configuration for all the functions in an Azure function project.

> How can I configure different PrefetchCount for each function?

- If all the functions are of same trigger type, then the recommended way by Microsoft is to define that setting in `host.json` and if it is function level code setting, then we can define in the Function Code like Function Disable attribute, it is proposed by @*SeanFeldman* in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72690004).

Answer (score 1):

Function App is configuration is applied to all Functions hosted in the same application. If you need to configure functions differently, you'll need to deploy those functions separately.